# How to run app from Xcode to iPhone as it is showing error of untrusted developer in iPhone and Macbook?

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS development and got stuck while transferring the app from MacBook to iPhone. I have connected my iPhone to my MacBook and then clicked on play button in my Xcode and it started showing error of untrusted developer in my iPhone and macbook both.

How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue:

1. Go to your iphone settings > General > VPN & Device Management :

[image]

1. Click on the account where it showing not trusted
2. Click on the link where it shows trust apple development :[image]
3. Click trust in popup :[image]

You’re done and your app will play smoothly on your device